# Openssl decryption not working

Tags: encryption, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to `encrypt` and `decrypt` text from command line using `openssl`. I am able to `encrypt` the text but I am not able to `decrypt` it back.

Here is how I am encrypting my text from command line:

```
➜  ~  echo -n 'Foo Bar' | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb  -K 123456789 | openssl enc -base64
```

Above command gives me following output:

```
RxmxBbcIFm5ZMiQIBYDr4Q==
```

Here is how I am trying to decrypt my text:

```
➜  ~  echo -n 'RxmxBbcIFm5ZMiQIBYDr4Q==' | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb  -K 123456789 | openssl enc -base64 -d
```

When I run the above command, I am not getting any output displayed on the screen:

```
➜  ~
```

Any idea how to decrypt the code from terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in -n flag in `echo` command. openssl required \n symbol for successful decryption.

compare

```
$ echo 'Foo Bar' | openssl enc -e -aes-128-ecb -base64 -K 123456789
eoGjHSco3ee2nOjibu7a3g==
```

and

```
echo -n 'Foo Bar' | openssl enc -e -aes-128-ecb -base64 -K 123456789
RxmxBbcIFm5ZMiQIBYDr4Q==
```

so it affects both, encryption and decryption.

```
$echo eoGjHSco3ee2nOjibu7a3g== | openssl enc -d -base64 -aes-128-ecb  -K 123456789
Foo Bar
$
```

and

```
echo RxmxBbcIFm5ZMiQIBYDr4Q== | openssl enc -d -base64 -aes-128-ecb -K 123456789 
Foo Bar$
```

Answer (score 1):

This part:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-ecb  -K 123456789
```

outputs raw data. When you try to decrypt it, you're adding `-base64`. The output isn't base64, so it fails. In your particular case, what you seem to mean is this:

```
echo -n 'Foo Bar' | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb  -K 123456789 | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -d -K 123456789
```

To encrypt and output base64, you want:

```
echo -n 'Foo Bar' | openssl enc -aes-128-ecb  -K 123456789 -base64
```

To decrypt and accept base64, you want:

```
echo 'RxmxBbcIFm5ZMiQIBYDr4Q==' | openssl enc -d -aes-128-ecb -K 123456789 -base64
```

As user1516873 notes, to use base64 input, you need a trailing newline, so no `-n`, but that wasn't the major problem in your code. It only applies to Base64, not generally to encryption or decryption. You could also use `-A` and not pass a newline. `-base64` is the same as `-a`, which is expecting a multi-line base64 block, while `-A` expects it all on one line (so doesn't need the \n).

Comment: Hi Rob, if I remove `-base64` then I am getting following output `��e���D��K�#�gg[��2�'h8�Nr��%`. How can I get the output in readable format. Thanks